# Is it advisable to use Angularjs 2 for a new project?

Tags: angular

I am about to start the development process of a web application. And I just wanted to know whether it is advisable to start it using Angularjs 2.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your project ? You could also use vanilla.js and be successful with it, without some details its hard to tell you if it is advisable :)

Comment: I posted the question because angular 2 is still in beta state. So i was wondering whether it is advisable or not. If it helps, I will post about the project details soon. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up an article here -> http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2015/12/angular-2-beta.html

what the article says about the beta is:

> Beta means we're now confident that most developers can be successful
>   building large applications using Angular 2.

And further

> Through developer preview and alpha we've worked closely with several
>   large projects here at Google including AdWords, GreenTea (Google's
>   internal CRM system), and Google Fiber.  In fact, just a few weeks ago
>   we saw Google Fiber launch on their new Angular 2 code base.

If google is working with it I would guess that its stable enough to build an application with it.

If its a big corporate application I would maybe wait ;) but if its internal or maybe nothing to big, meaning you could lose lots of money, you could give it a try

Comment: Its an internal project, so yeah i will give it a try :). thanks.